# How to create cache on infinispan cluster during the startup

Tags: infinispan, spring-cache

I have following configuration using

```
org.infinispan', name: 'infinispan-spring4-common', version: '9.1.7.Final'
```

The question is how can I create cache programmatically? or how can I create cache during the infinispan server bootup?

I am unable to create a tag 'infinispan-as-spring-cache-provider' can someone help me for that?

```java
@Configuration
@Profile("infinispan-standalone")
@EnableCaching
public class InfinispanStandaloneConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InfinispanCacheConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public RemoteCacheManager remoteCacheManager(@Value("${infinispan.remote.server-list}") String serverlist,
                                                 @Value("infinispan.admin.user") String user,
                                                 @Value("infinispan.admin.password") String pwd) {
        logger.info("inside the remote cache manager");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("infinispan.client.hotrod.client_intelligence", "BASIC");
        properties.setProperty("infinispan.client.hotrod.marshaller", "org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.GenericJBossMarshaller");

        RemoteCacheManager remoteCacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(new ConfigurationBuilder().addServers(serverlist).withProperties(properties)
                .security().authentication().username(user).password(pwd)
                .build());
        remoteCacheManager.getCache("cart",true);
        return remoteCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringRemoteCacheManager cacheManager(RemoteCacheManager remoteCacheManager) {
        return new SpringRemoteCacheManager(remoteCacheManager);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Infinispan 9.2, where you can use the following:

`remoteCacheManager.administration().getOrCreateCache("cart", "template-name");`

provided "template-name" is a configuration template defined on the server.
Alternatively, you can also pass an XML configuration for the cache:

`String xml = "<infinispan><cache-container><distributed-cache name="cart"><expiration interval="10000" lifespan="10" max-idle="10"/></distributed-cache></cache-container></infinispan>";
remoteCacheManager.administration().getOrCreateCache("cart", new XMLConfiguration(xml));`

Comment: Getting following exception  
    
'org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.TransportException:: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=95 returned server error (status=0x85): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported operation invoked: AUTH_MECH_LIST] with root cause'

Comment: Using the following code snippet

`RemoteCacheManager remoteCacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(new ConfigurationBuilder().addServers(serverlist).withProperties(properties)
                .security()
                    .authentication()
                        .saslMechanism("DIGEST-MD5").callbackHandler(new LoginHandler(user, pwd.toCharArray(), "ManagementRealm")).enable()`